# Could you explain the derivation of the expectation equation of equation 3.6 in Sutton & Barto?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reward-functions

[image]

I don't understand the last equality.

Here is my derivation
$r(s,a,s')=\sum_{r\in R} r p(r|s,a,s')=\sum_{r\in R} r \frac{p(s,a,s'|r)p(r)}{p(s,a,s')}$

Could you give me the correct steps to derive them?

Thank you

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Why does the definition of the reward function $r(s, a, s')$ involve the term $p(s' \mid s, a)$?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/20244/why-does-the-definition-of-the-reward-function-rs-a-s-involve-the-term-p), although maybe the answers don't provide the full derivation.

Comment: There's even another question which may be a duplicate of this. I think Dennis provided an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that

$\sum_{r\in R} r p(r|s,a,s') = \sum_{r\in R} r \frac{p(s,a,s',r)}{p(s,a,s')} = \sum_{r\in R} r \frac{p(s',r|s,a)}{p(s'|s,a)} $ by cancelling $p(s,a)$.